# Why this game based on requestAnimationFrame sometimes got stuck (but CPU not stuck)?

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, requestanimationframe

I am creating a free throw game.

The rule is very simple - to click the mouse and make the ball stay at the center of a cross.

I have tried many times and the problem is that sometimes the game would get stuck.

I'm new to `requestAnimationFrame`. Is there anything I've missed?

```js
$('#easy').click(()=>{
  createFreeThrow("#baseel",2);
});
$('#mid').click(()=>{
  createFreeThrow("#baseel",5);
});
$('#hard').click(()=>{
  createFreeThrow("#baseel",7);
});
$('#god').click(()=>{
  createFreeThrow("#baseel",9);
});
function createFreeThrow(base_element, difficulty_factor){

  var $svg = $(`<svg class="ft_svg" style="background:beige" width="300" height="150">
    <rect x="100" y="70" width="100" height="10" fill="red"/>
    <rect x="145" y="25" width="10" height="100" fill="red"/>
    <circle class="ft_circle1" cx="100" cy="75" r="10" fill="green" />
    <circle class="ft_circle2" cx="150" cy="25" r="10" fill="green" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="10" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="2,2" stroke-width="2"></circle>
    </svg>`);
  $(base_element).empty().append($svg);

  var step = difficulty_factor;
  var horizontal_animation_done = false;
  var vertical_animation_done = false;
  var $circle1 = $svg.find('.ft_circle1');
  var $circle2 = $svg.find('.ft_circle2');
  var cx_result;
  var cy_result;
  var FPS = 60;
  var handled_hori = false;
  var handled_vert = false;
  $svg.one('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (handled_hori) return;
    handled_hori = true;
    horizontal_animation_done = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      $svg.one('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (handled_vert) return;
        handled_vert = true;
        vertical_animation_done = true;
        // console.log('end vert', e);
      })
    }, 90)
  })
  function renderHorizontal(){
    var cx = $circle1.attr('cx')/1;
    cx += step;
    $circle1.attr('cx', cx);
    if(cx > 200) {
      step = -difficulty_factor;
    }
    if(cx < 100) {
      step = difficulty_factor;
    }
    // If horizontal animation is done, save a result and start the vertical animation.
    if(horizontal_animation_done) {
      cx_result = cx;
      window.requestAnimationFrame(renderVertical);
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
      requestAnimationFrame(renderHorizontal);
    }
    , 1000 / FPS);
  }

  function renderVertical(){
    var cy = $circle2.attr('cy')/1;
    cy += step;
    $circle2.attr('cy', cy);
    var from_center = 1 - Math.abs(cy - 75)/50;
    if(cy > 125) {
      step = -difficulty_factor;
    }
    if(cy < 25) {
      step = difficulty_factor;
    }
    // If vertical animation is done, save a score and stop the animation
    if(vertical_animation_done) {
      cy_result = cy;
      freeThrowResult(cx_result, cy_result);
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
      requestAnimationFrame(renderVertical);
    }
    , 1000 / FPS);
  }
  // start playing at beginning
  window.requestAnimationFrame(renderHorizontal);

  function freeThrowResult(cx,cy) {
    // console.log(cx, cy);
    $('#score').val(JSON.stringify([cx,cy]));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="baseel"></div>
<button id="easy">Easy</button>
<button id="mid">Mid</button>
<button id="hard">Hard</button>
<button id="god">God</button>
<input type="text" id="score"/>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ requestAnimationFrame(renderVertical); }` looks funky

Comment: Yes, `setTimeout(function(){requestAnimationFrame(renderVertical);} , 1000 / FPS);` is like a Formula1 being transported in a truck from one race to the other. Won't go faster than the truck...

Comment: @Kaiido it's `vertical_animation_done`

Comment: @Bravo May I know why the `setTimeout` looks funky?

Comment: seems odd to put a requestAnimationFrame inside one